# Problema con for y insert en un Text

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy haciendo un mini programa de encriptacion de mensajes y tengo un problema Cuando imprimo la cadena de texto "incriptada" sale perfecto, pero cuando intento agregarlo al widget Text solo agrega una letra en vez del mensaje "incriptado" entero

```
import random
from random import shuffle
import tkinter
from tkinter import Tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import Text
from tkinter import Label
from tkinter import END
from tkinter import INSERT

ventana = Tk()

class main():
    def __init__(self):
        labelMensaje = Label(ventana,text="Mensaje")
        labelMensaje.config(fg="red",bg="black")
        labelMensaje.place(x=150,y=0,width=200)

        self.textoMensaje = Text(ventana)
        self.textoMensaje.place(x=150,y=30,width=200)
        self.textoMensaje.insert(INSERT,"Escribe lo que quieras.")

        botonEncriptar = ttk.Button(ventana,text="Encriptar",command=self.encriptar)
        botonEncriptar.place(x=400,y=100)

    def encriptar(self):
        cifrado = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l",
            "m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","z","y","z"]
        shuffle(cifrado)

        mensajeOriginal = self.textoMensaje.get(1.0,END)
        for i in mensajeOriginal:
            x = i.replace(i,random.choice(cifrado))
            print(x,end="")
            self.textoMensaje.delete(1.0,END)
            self.textoMensaje.insert(INSERT,x)

main()
ventana.geometry("500x500")
ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás limpiando el contenido del widget `Text` en cada iteración del ciclo, por lo que al final solo el último carácter resultante de la última iteración del `for` queda en el widget.

La solución es simplemente mover la línea:

```
self.textoMensaje.delete(1.0, END)
```

desde el interior del `for` a antes de éste, pero después del `get`:

```
def encriptar(self):
    cifrado = ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l",
        "m","n","ñ","o","p","q","r","s","t","v","w","z","y","z"]
    shuffle(cifrado)

    mensajeOriginal = self.textoMensaje.get(1.0, END)
    self.textoMensaje.delete(1.0, END)
    for i in mensajeOriginal:
        x = i.replace(i, random.choice(cifrado))
        print(x, end="")
        self.textoMensaje.insert(INSERT, x)
```